# Why can I not use coalesce with a TempData property in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the following code, `invoices` will always be null. Doesn't matter if `TempData` contains the information or not.

```
var invoices = TempData["invoices"] as List<Invoice> ?? new List<Invoice>();
```

Instead, the following must be done:

```
var invoices = TempData["invoices"] as List<Invoice>;
invoices = invoices ?? new List<Invoice>();
```

Can anyone explain why? I like the `??` operator and I want to know it's safe to use.

EDIT: I had given a simple set of code above that show my issue. This was because it was cleaner to read than my static variables and class that wouldn't make sense to anyone else. Because I've gotten close votes and apparently what I'm seeing isn't possible, I'm posting a screenshot. In the shot you can see that the variable jobs can NEVER be null due to coalesce. But directly after the code line with the breakpoint hits, it is in fact null. Also, in the watch below you can see that the TempData object was not null so the coalesce wasn't really needed.

[image]

Comment: not really sure about your question, but there is no difference between the two code snippet in your question. ?? is [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: Well, try it. There's supposed to be no code difference, but I assure you there is. That's the reason for the post.

Comment: I just did, it works fine, there is no compiler error or even a warning from Re-Sharper

Comment: I updated my question and posted a picture. I agree with you, it should work this way. I don't need it fixed as I have a workaround; I'm just trying to understand why it's really null at this point.

Comment: that is strange, try restarting Visual studio / IIS / Computer and see if that problem goes away. Also try Rebuild, Clean/Rebuild and see if starts behaving normally.

Comment: Good grief. Cleaned and rebuilt. No changes. Closed and restarted VS. Intellisense showed null still, but low and behold when I stepped through the next line and expected a null reference exception, there was none. It was working. And after the next line 'jobs' showed up as a List. Apparently the restart fixed the program, but there's a bug in Intellisense where it won't show jobs correctly until I go a line of operation past the assignment line. Never seen that before.

Comment: Were you using Edit and Continue?

Comment: Nope. I was simply running when I hit a null reference exception. So I started debugging. VS2013 is still messed up but the application is working.